# Simple query generates Error 3078 "The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query"

Tags: sql-server, vb6, odbc, dao

Any suggestions how to restructure this simple query?

Hitting a SQL Server Database using DAO via VB6 (updated old code to work with new database) and somehow this query in one of the apps is giving fits.

```
Select I.sType, Count(I.BarcodeID) AS CountOfID 
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT sType, BarcodeID From [Ready]) as I 
GROUP BY I.sType 
ORDER BY sType
```

I've pasted the query into SQL Enterprise Manager and it runs just fine as expected.  It worked fine hitting the original Access DB.  But somehow the DAO via ODBC hitting the SQL Server is generating:

*"The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot find the input table or query"*

Things I've tried:

- Removing the ()
- Removing "as I" and "I." notation.
- Brackets around [Ready] and without (thinking it might be reserved
  keyword).
- **Confirmed that the connection is to the ODBC for Sql Server (this connection is used for other queries too.**

Checked SQL profiling tool and the query **is making it to the server** (edited, I was checking the wrong tool on SQL Express)

EDIT: just to sate everyone's concern that I'm not really hitting SQL Server, I edited the SQL command to an even simpler

```
SELECT DISTINCT sType, BarcodeID From [Ready]
```

and it works correctly ON the same connection, so the connection is 100% confirmed to be SQL Server, the error message is in error (reported "Access").

So the problem is with no doubt the query FROM a query.

***UPDATE:***

Definitely confirmed my suspicions that the query, albeit a normal one, is not working with ADO-> ODBC-> Sql Server.

The first step SQL is doing is trying to validate the columns, etc.. of the "from" table (which in this case is not a table, but a query itself).

When I run a basic `SELECT DISTINCT sType, BarcodeID From [Ready]` SQL checks the columns, keys, indexes, etc of the table called "Ready" (`exec sp_special_columns N'Ready',NULL,NULL,N'V',N'T',N'U'`), then proceeds to return the results.

When I use a subquery, SQL is firing the same check on the table def, but for a **table** called `SELECT DISTINCT sType, BarcodeID From [Ready]` which of course does not exist and it returns an error (`exec sp_special_columns N'SELECT DISTINCT sType, BarcodeID From [Ready]',NULL,NULL,N'V',N'T',N'U'`).  VB6/ADO is reporting correctly that SQL says the table is not found.  So apparently this query from a query stumps the capabilities of ADO->ODBC...

Comment: Are you sure you're hitting the right database? "Microsoft Jet" would suggest Access, not SQL Server

Comment: @Diado -- Good suggestion and yes.  I should have added that I checked that as well.  The connection is clearly to the ODBC connection to my SQL Server.  But you're right the message made me immediately confirm that no Access was still in play.  In fact the "folder" where the Access MDBs has been renamed so it cannot possibly find them. :(

Comment: Considering that the OP states *"Checked SQL Profiler and the query is not even making it to the server"* @Diado I think that the this pretty much confirms the problem as well. JET can't be used to connect to SQL Server, it's for connecting to pre 2007 Office files (like Access and Excel files). 2010+ uses ACE, and SQl Server uses ODBC. The fact that the error is stating JET clearly show the right driver isn't being used. I suggest the OP shares their code, as the SQL statement isn't the problem here.

Comment: @Lamu -- See reply above.  Definitely on the right connection, so it's the SQL.

Comment: @klkitchens Can you share the code you're using to connect to the database?

Comment: @Diado -- Will look at parsing that out later if necessary.  But not sure chasing that rabbit trail would be of any benefit to determining the cause of the SQL failing.  I know it's the normal "script" for troubleshooting, but it's 100% using the right connection and works with all other SQL in the application.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

since the issue is clearly the `Select FROM (Select From)` structure of querying a query being incompatible with ADO->ODBC->SQL Server, my solution was simply to make the subquery a view in SQL and alter the query to select from that.